# Unwanted reloading after using jQuery load for second time

Tags: jquery

I use this code to refresh just a div (contains a form) after sending form via Ajax:

```
$('#divid').load(location.href + ' #divid>*', '');
```

That is work for first time and then, reload whole page for next clicks.
I do not want reload whole page.

Comment: probably your click is on the same div content? can you provide where you are clicking and your click handler?

Comment: @Reflective Yes exactly. I was moved my buttons out of that div. I was checked it and everything OK! But why jQuery does not render them again?